# Why I cannot use the extension R with Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

```
#include "rcpp_add.h"
using namespace Rcpp ;

SEXP rcpp_add(SEXP a, SEXP b)
{

  std::vector< std::map<std::string,int> > v;
  std::map<std::string,int> m1;
  std::map<std::string,int> m2;

  int ax=Rcpp::as<int>(a);
  int bx=Rcpp::as<int>(b);

  m1["a"]=ax;
  m1["b"]=bx;

  m2["c"]=2;
  m2["d"]=20;

  v.push_back(m1);
  v.push_back(m2);

  return Rcpp::wrap(v);
}
```

This code can be loaded in interactive `R`, but it tells me error when I use `SEXP a, SEXP b`. Why? When I don't use the `SEXP a, SEPX b` the function is correct in the `R` environment

Comment: So what is the problem, just leave out SEXP? The integration of C++ and R can be done the old fashioned way (I believe including SEXP), or using Rcpp. You now mix both approaches, leading to issues...

Comment: If everything else fails, you could consider reading the _copious_ documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description of the error messages doesn't make much sense, but here's a simpler version that works for me:

```
#include "Rcpp.h"
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List rcpp_add(int a, int b) {

  std::vector< std::map<std::string,int> > v;
  std::map<std::string,int> m1;
  std::map<std::string,int> m2;

  m1["a"] = a;
  m1["b"] = b;

  m2["c"] = 2;
  m2["d"] = 20;

  v.push_back(m1);
  v.push_back(m2);

  return Rcpp::wrap(v);
}
```